# Make inherited val public

Tags: scala, protected, access-modifiers

There exists (outside of my code)

```
trait Foo {
  protected val bar = 0
}
```

I want have a class `FooImpl` that extends `Foo` and makes `bar` public.

I heard that subclasses could increase the visibility of their inherited members.

How do I do this?

---

I tried

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  override val logger = super.logger
}
```

But got the error:

```
super may be not be used on value logger
```

Answer (score 2):

It works if you make `logger` a def instead of a val.

```
trait Foo {
    protected def logger = 0
}

class FooImpl extends Foo {
    override val logger = super.logger
}
```

If `Foo` isn't defined by you, you may be out of luck outside of a solution involving reflection.

See [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1938) and [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1938).

Comment: Can't you use `def` the other way around? `override def logger = super.logger`?

Comment: Doesn't seem so? Unless you mean make them both defs.

Answer (score 1):

You could increase visibility of methods.

When you declare field with wider visibility you **declare new field**.